# Bringing $\frac{\sin(2n+1)x+\sin x}{\cos(2n+1)x-\cos x}$ to a simpler form

Tags: trigonometry

The exercise asks me to bring $$\frac{\sin(2n+1)x+\sin x}{\cos(2n+1)x-\cos x}$$
to a simpler form.

Textbook only says to use previous exercise as a model but previous exercise was $$\frac{\sin5x-\sin3x}{\cos5x-\cos3x} $$
All I can think of is that it's missing brackets around $(2n+1)x$. In that case I know it reduces to $-\cot(nx)$

Comment: Yes, there should be brackets, formally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the identities for difference of $\sin$ and $\cos$,
$$\sin(2n+1)x +\sin x = 2\sin(n+1)x\cos nx \\ 
\cos(2n+1)x - \cos x = -2\sin(n+1)x \sin nx$$
Therefore the expression is $$-\cot nx$$

Comment: I think you mistook a "+" for a "-" in the first one

Comment: It was "+sin x"

Comment: @jhjhjh Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html